# Ember.js: showing multiple database-backed resources/models in the same page/route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm writing a small test app using Ember, in the form of a budget manager. I have a Budget object, which contains general properties like the monthly limit and a description. I also have a set of Expense objects, which contain a name, the amount spent, etc. Both are retrieved from a server using Ember Data's REST adapter.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="budget">
    <h2>{{name}} (€ {{amount}})</h2>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="expenses">
    <ul id="expense-list">
        {{#each model}}
            {{render "expense" this}}
        {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>

    <!-- expense template -->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="expense">
        <li>
            <label>{{description}}</label>
            <label class="subtle">{{formatDate time}}</label>
            <label class="amount">{{amount}}</label>
        </li>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:5000',
    namespace: 'outthepocket/api'
});

// Model
App.Expense = DS.Model.extend({
    amount: DS.attr('number'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    time: DS.attr('date')
});

App.Budget = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    amount: DS.attr('number')
});

// Routes
App.Router.map( function() {
    this.resource('budget');
    this.resource('expenses');
});

App.ExpensesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function()
    {
        return this.store.find('expense');
    }
});

App.BudgetRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function()
    {
        return this.store.find('budget', 1);
    }
});
```

Following the architecture I see in all the Ember tutorials, there is an ExpensesRoute with the list of expenses as its model, and a BudgetRoute with the selected budget as its model. This works great as long as I go through the proper URL to see each resource:

- **myapp.html#budget** renders the budget template with data from the server.
- **myapp.html#expenses** renders the expenses template with data from the server.

The problem I'm having now is that I want to **display both templates, with their data, on one page** (the index page). I've tried two solutions for this:

- **Solution 1**: Have separate routes and templates and call {{render budget}} and {{render expenses}} in the main application template. This renders both templates, but without any data.
- **Solution 2**: Have just an IndexRoute and return both budget and expenses from its model property, rendering them into the index template. This more or less works, but seems counter to Ember's otherwise nice separation of different resources, routes and controllers.

Any thoughts? I've been through five or six tutorials and Ember's official guide, but none of those have made clear how to assemble a one-page web app with multiple templates backed by multiple resources without having to link to different pages/routes.

Comment: "...none of those have made clear how to assemble a one-page web app with multiple templates backed by multiple resources without having to link to different pages/routes."

You have hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Ember.RSVP.hash` to load more than one model, in a single object:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function()
    {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            expenses: this.store.find('expense'),
            budget: this.store.find('budget', 1)
        })
    }
});
```

And in the template you can access each resolved promise by the key:

`{{expenses}}` will return the result from `this.store.find('expense')` promise and `{{budget}}` the result from `this.store.find('budget', 1)` promise.

So in your index template you will able to do:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    {{render "expenses" expenses}}
    {{render "budget" budget}}
</script>
```

Comment: Works great Márcio, thanks! Would you consider this the canonical Ember way of doing this? It's odd to me that I haven't encountered Ember.RSVP anywhere in the guides, yet it seems like the type of thing I'm trying to do would be pretty common in a lot of web apps.

Comment: You are welcome! Yes this is the best way to do this in my experience. RSVP is the promises api used for ember, you can find some documentation [here](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js). I think that your problem need to be present in the [ember cookbook](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/), like you said this is a common problem.

Comment: @KennyDeriemaeker You and I have the same frustration. Pretty common real-world app patterns seem to have little to no example materials in the guides or blogosphere. And the idiomatic solution always seems to be some obscure (to new users) method buried in the API. The guides are too granular and fragmented to be useful a lot of the time. Every time I've started on an Ember app, it hardly takes me any time to reach a point where the architecture outpaces the level of depth in the guides and it's off to stackoverflow with fingers crossed.